# t-test analysis is different from t-test of that variable in regression

Tags: r, regression, t-test

When I run following commands:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- 1:500
set.seed(1)
x1 <- sample(c(0,1),500, replace = T, prob = c(.8,.2))
set.seed(1)
x2 <- rnorm(500, mean = 5, sd = 3)
set.seed(1)
x3 <- sample(c(1:100), size = 500, replace = T)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)
t.test(y ~ x1, data = df)
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df)
summary(fit1)
```

Y variable's average value with respect to x1's 0 and 1 value is not significantly different, but when I include x1 along with other variable, it become significant. Could you please tell me the reason behind it.

http://rextester.com/QUD34609

Comment: Since the variable is not at all changing the mean value individually why would it appear while combining with other variables?

Answer (score 4):

Let's construct an illuminating example.

```
set.seed(0)
x1 <- sort(runif(100))
x2 <- rev(x1)    # just reverse x1 
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(100, 0, 0.1)

# x1 is not significant
summary(lm(y ~ x1))

# x2 is not significant (of course)
summary(lm(y ~ x2))

# but now, they are both highly significant (of course)
summary(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))
```